# Update throws "Invalid column name" when the query doesn't mention that column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that does a simple update on a table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateModel]
(
    @status int,
    @name nvarchar(127),
-- ... omited for brevity ...
    @tourlink nvarchar(256),
    @Original_id int
)
AS
UPDATE dbo.models
SET 
    status = @status,
    name = @name,
-- ... omited for brevity ...
    tourlink = @tourlink
WHERE (id = @Original_id)
```

(omited portions of this procedure are simply more parameter definitions and updates, nothing fancy)

This procedure worked fine until I added a new column to the underlying table `dbo.models` called `tourlinkcoverimage` of type `nvarchar(256)`.  This field is nullable, so I shouldn't need to include it in this update statement (it's updated separately in another procedure.)

I can set the value of this column and query it's value successfully, but the procedure above throws the following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'tourlinkcoverimage'.
```

Why does this procedure throw this error?  How can I fix it?

Comment: check for a trigger on that table.  My guess is that one exists and it's doing some form of insert into a target table.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth that was it!  Thanks!  If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s I know that.  I inherited this database, and there is code that hits that, which makes changing it more of a headache than it's worth.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth, would you mind posting that as answer. So that it will help future readers as well. Else I will do it and get the rep :)

Comment: That's correct as stated by @marc_s. You should rather use `usp_` which kind a stands for `user stored proc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for a trigger on the table.  My guess is that one exists and it's doing some form of insert into a target table.

> "Triggers are like voodoo code; you update a value, and suddenly the
>   lights go off in the building next door" - Richard Campbell, PASS
>   presentation, 2008